# Not sure why my rake seed file isn't running

Tags: ruby, rake, database-migration, faker

here is my seed file :

```
require 'pry'
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'faker'

Consumer.delete_all
AlcoholicBeverage.delete_all
Intake.delete_all

100.times do 
    name = Faker::Name.first_name
    sex= Faker::Gender.binary_type
    weight= Faker::Number.between(from: 1, to: 10)
    Consumer.create!(name:name,sex:sex,weight:weight)
end

ingredients=RestClient.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teijo/iba-cocktails/master/recipes.json")
@ingredients_data=JSON.parse(ingredients)

@ingredients_data.collect do |x,y|
    AlcoholicBeverage.create(cocktail_name: x["name"],glass: x["glass"],garnish: x["garnish"],preparation: x["preparation"])
end

100.times do 
    consumer_id = rand(1..100)
    alcoholic_beverage_id = rand(1..100)
    Intake.create!(consumer_id: consumer_id, alcoholic_beverage_id:alcoholic_beverage_id)
end
```

here is my gemfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "activerecord", '~> 5.2'
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "sqlite3", '~> 1.3.6'
gem "pry"
gem "require_all"
gem "faker"
gem 'rest-client'
```

I've already ran my migrations fine.. so I'm not sure why nothing is showing up when I enter rake db:seed into my terminal.
Any advice or help will be much appreciated. I've also tried including require 'faker' in my seed file as well but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: _nothing is showing up_? Not even an error message? The command just returns empty without any feedback?

Comment: careful: calling `delete_all` doesn't reset your auto increment column, and associations won't be set with your `rand`

Comment: Open up a rails console with `rails c` and then paste in everything in the file - do you get an error?  Do you see records being created?  There has to be some indication of success or failure.

Comment: Perhaps you have two seeds.rb files? Where are you keeping the above `seeds.rb` file? It sould be here `db/seeds.rb`. Note that the file name is PLURAL: seed**s**.rb

Comment: @JoshBrody how can I reset my auto increment column?

Answer (score 0):

This alternative approach will help you avoid missing data, by not depending on your ids being from 1 to 100:

```
consumers = 100.times.map do 
  name = Faker::Name.first_name
  sex= Faker::Gender.binary_type
  weight= Faker::Number.between(from: 1, to: 10)
  Consumer.create!(name:name,sex:sex,weight:weight)
end

ingredients=RestClient.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teijo/iba-cocktails/master/recipes.json")
@ingredients_data=JSON.parse(ingredients)

beverages = @ingredients_data.map do |x,y|
  AlcoholicBeverage.create(cocktail_name: x["name"],glass: x["glass"],garnish: x["garnish"],preparation: x["preparation"])
end

100.times do 
  Intake.create!(consumer: consumers.shuffle.first, alcoholic_beverage: beverages.shuffle.first)
end
```